# How to mix 2 shaders depending on distance from camera

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I want to mix 2 shaders in a way, that part of a mesh that is more far away from camera are using one of my shaders, and part of the mesh that is closer to my shaders is using another shader, with soft transition between them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

Set up the nodes as pictured below. Add ***Camera Data*** node (*Add* [<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>]-->*Input*-->*Camera Data*), then ***Math Node*** (*Add*-->*Converter*-->*Math*). Optionaly you may add the ***Color Ramp*** node (*Add*-->*Converter*-->*Color Ramp*).
[image]

With the ***Math Node*** set to *Substract* try to experiment with its value (the closer to the object camera is the lower value should be).
[image]
[image]

Use ***Color Ramp*** node to make the transition between colours/ textures soft or sharp.
[image]

### [image]

Edit:
For smoother transitions you can use other math nodes in combination. For instance put a logarithm node between the Camera Data Node and Subtract node. Change the color ramp to Cardinal and also change the direction of the ramp. Set the bottom value of the Logarithm to 15.0 and the bottom value of the Subtract to .250. Subtract becomes an offset of sorts.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is there a way to make transition more smooth? I'm using color ramp node, but i want even smoother transition.

Comment: Try to connect the Math (Substract) node directly to the Fac of Mix Shader (delete the Color Ramp node). You may also try to change the mode of the Color Ramp node from Ease to  Linear or Cardinal. Hope it'll help you.