# How to colorize object depending on camera position in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to get something like this  : https://github.com/Jmion/Alpano_v2 , with no success. 
I've been testing this solution : [Change color of an object depending on camera view (cycles render)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73608/change-color-of-an-object-depending-on-camera-view-cycles-render)

but I can't manage to make it.

I use BlenderGIS to import a DEM, I create a material with the "analyze" option which permit to colorize it depending on altitudes values (Z) .
What I  want is to render camera positions with color distance information.

[image]

Would someone be kind to help me?

PS: I use Blender 2.79b

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]

I'm on the way to succeed I think, I can fix the distance by color : my colorRamp shows values from 0 to 360, I decided to noramlize until 30000 meters, so 1 value represents 83.33 meters.  Another thing I'm not able to reproduce is the ridge lines and the volume aspect of the DEM or quad wireframe.

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Hi. When you say "I can't manage to make it work", what do you mean? What happens? What is your current setup? Please use the [edit] link below your question to add more details.

Comment: I created a video tutorial about using empties to control gradient textures that you may find useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPvYAHc9vCE

Comment: Nice tut, I keep it in my favorites, but I won't need empties .